# SQL Recursive CTE - Keep reference to a parent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following structure

```
userId      userName         managerId
----------- ---------------- -----------
1           John             NULL
2           Charles          1
3           Nicolas          NULL
4           Neil             3
```

And I have another table which has the following

```
userId      shareId         
----------- -----------
1           1001             
3           1002
```

So I do the following query to get my recursive CTE:

```
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT userId, userName, managerId,0 AS steps
  FROM dbo.Users
  WHERE userId = 7

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.userId, mgr.userName, mgr.managerId, usr.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS mgr
      ON usr.managerId = mgr.userId
)
SELECT * FROM UserCTE AS u;
```

Which produces the following result

```
userId      userName         managerId   steps       
----------- ---------------- ----------- ----------- 
1           John             NULL        0           
2           Charles          1           1           
3           Nicolas          NULL        0           
4           Neil             3           1
```

OK so what I want to know is the `shareId` for the users that have it, and also for the users that belong to them.

**Expected result** :

```
userId      userName         managerId   steps       shareId
----------- ---------------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           John             NULL        0           1001
2           Charles          1           1           1001
3           Nicolas          NULL        0           1002
4           Neil             3           1           1002
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join `Share table` with the `Users` table in anchor query of `Recursive CTE`.  Try this.

```
;WITH UserCTE
     AS (SELECT c.userId,
                userName,
                managerId,
                0 AS steps,
                shareId
         FROM   dbo.Users c
                LEFT JOIN share_table s
                  ON c.userId = s.userId
         WHERE  managerId IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT mgr.userId,
                mgr.userName,
                mgr.managerId,
                usr.steps + 1 AS steps,
                usr.shareId
         FROM   UserCTE AS usr
                INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS mgr
                        ON usr.userId = mgr.managerId)
SELECT *
FROM   UserCTE AS u
ORDER  BY userId;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do `left join` on cte table and usershare table.

```
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT userId, userName, managerId,0 AS steps
  FROM dbo.Users
  where   managerId IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.userId, mgr.userName, mgr.managerId, usr.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
  INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS mgr
  ON usr.userId = mgr.managerId
  )
SELECT * FROM UserCTE AS u
left join userShare us
on u.managerId = us.userId
or u.userId = us.userId
order by u.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an `OR` in the join between the `UserCTE` table and the `share` table. For example:

```
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT userId, userName, managerId,0 AS steps
  FROM dbo.Users
  WHERE userId = 7

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.userId, mgr.userName, mgr.managerId, usr.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS mgr
      ON usr.managerId = mgr.userId
)
SELECT * FROM UserCTE AS u
INNER JOIN [share table] AS s
    ON u.userId = s.userId OR u.managerId s.userId;
```

However, this has the potential to procedure duplicates if there is greater than one level managerial hierarchy. I.e. A manager also has a manager. An alternative is to make two left joins one on the `userId` column of the `UserCTE` table to the `share` table and the other to `managerId` column of the `UserCTE` table to the `share` table. You can then use a `CASE` statement on the `shareId` column to decide which one you require. See below:

```
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT userId, userName, managerId,0 AS steps
  FROM dbo.Users
  WHERE userId = 7

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.userId, mgr.userName, mgr.managerId, usr.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS mgr
      ON usr.managerId = mgr.userId
)
SELECT
    u.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN su.shareId is not null THEN su.shareId
        WHEN sm.shareId is not null THEN sm.shareId
        ELSE null END as shareID
FROM UserCTE AS u
LEFT JOIN [share table] AS su
    ON u.userId = s.userId
LEFT JOIN [share table] AS sm
    ON u.managerId = s.userId;
```

Hope this helps.